# Sublime REPL bug while runing Swift in Linux

Tags: swift, linux, sublimetext3

I have set my Sublime REPL to work with Swift, but I am facing some problems. Note that the below code runs without errors in the terminal.

The following code:

```
import Foundation

func execCommand(command: String, args: [String]) -> String {
    if !command.hasPrefix("/") {
        let commandFull = execCommand(command: "/usr/bin/which", args: [command]).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return execCommand(command: commandFull, args: args)
    } else {
        let proc = Process()
        proc.launchPath = command
        proc.arguments = args
        let pipe = Pipe()
        proc.standardOutput = pipe
        proc.launch()
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    }
}

let commandOutput = execCommand(command:"file-roller", args:["Hello, I am here!"])
print("Command output: \(commandOutput)")
```

Causes errors in the REPL, which in turn complains about Foundation building.

```
/usr/lib/swift/CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h:25:10: note: while building module 'SwiftGlibc' imported from /usr/lib/swift/CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h:25:
#include <sys/types.h>
         ^
```

My swift REPL configuration is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Swift",
                 "id": "repl_swift",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "external_id": "swift",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": {
                            "osx": ["/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift"],
                            "linux":["swift"]},
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "additional_scopes": ["swift"],
                    "syntax": "Packages/Swift/Syntaxes/Swift.tmLanguage"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

I can't really figure out what is happening there, it seems the configuration is ok. Any suggestion of action?